# How to (automatically ) detect the steady-part of vowels?

Tags: corpora, spoken-language

Please I need your help ASAP,
I need to segment an audio corpus of 4 hours , and I need a tool or script to detect the steady part of vowels and place the boundaries .

Comment: By "steady part", do you mean sections of a vowel where F1-F3 are roughly the same e.g. within 100 Hz?

Comment: For audio segmentation there is a CLARIN service called WebMAUS, see this answer http://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/19957/how-to-read-spectrograms-using-praat-script/20060#20060